# Magnific Popup Set up

Tags: popup

I'm just getting back into web development so forgive me if I sound ignorant. I'm trying to set up a lightbox effect using Magnific Popup. I love it because all of the examples are using responsive design.

I've followed instructions here: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#mfp-build-tool

And here: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/js-animated-how-to-implement-jquery-magnific-popup-lightbox-plugin.html#prettyPhoto/0/

A few times and I don't understand why the pop up isn't coming up. It just links me to a new window with the image on it and not a pop up.

I have this in my head tag:

```
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/magnific-popup.css">

<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/magnific-popup.css"> 

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>


</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    image: {
        verticalFit: true
    }

});

});
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="images/logo.png"     title="TITLE">
<img src="images/print.png" border="0" align="center" class="image2"     /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and had the same setup as you. I thought I had called the jQuery library already, but apparently not, because as soon as I added the code (below) before closing my HEAD, everything started working! I know this answer is about a year belated, but maybe it will help others in the future.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and took me a while to figure it out, so thought I would share. You have to load the .js files in proper sequence or it will not work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="">

    <head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="../styles/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"> 
    </head>
    
    <body id="top">
    
    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    
    <div class="popup-gallery">
        <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_b.jpg" title="The Cleaner"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
        <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8558295631_0f56c1284f_b.jpg" title="Winter Dance"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8558295631_0f56c1284f_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
        <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8225/8558295635_b1c5ce2794_b.jpg" title="The Uninvited Guest"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8225/8558295635_b1c5ce2794_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
        <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8383/8563475581_df05e9906d_b.jpg" title="Oh no, not again!"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8383/8563475581_df05e9906d_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
        <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8559402846_8b7f82e05d_b.jpg" title="Swan Lake"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8559402846_8b7f82e05d_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
        <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8558295467_e89e95e05a_b.jpg" title="The Shake"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8558295467_e89e95e05a_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
        <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8378/8559402848_9fcd90d20b_b.jpg" title="Who's that, mommy?"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8378/8559402848_9fcd90d20b_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
              delegate: 'a',
              type: 'image',
              tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
              mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
              gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                navigateByImgClick: true,
                preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
              },
              image: {
                tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
                titleSrc: function(item) {
                  return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
                }
              }
            });
          });
        </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```